# MySQL copying crashed database into new fresh installed database

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, innodb, restore, database-backups

we are using Mysql 5.7 with InnoDB on Ubuntu server.

I have the full content of the "/var/lib/mysql" directory of our crashed mysql server. It contains all the directories for the databases and other configuration files, and ssl keys, etc.

Now we have installed a new fresh installation into a new server and we want the new server to run with our existing data that should also include our existing database user logins. 
We tried to point to "data_dir" configuration of the new server into our existing mysql directory which was copied to "/var/lib/mysql_old" directory. Unfortunately the service is not starting. 
Do you have any idea what might be wrong with my steps? Or if you have more ideas to please let me know. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the service is not starting then you should have an error message.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The error message is quite generic and I got this types of error message on various cases. I am more interested to know about the actual steps To be followed.

Comment: I don't think 'data_dir' is the only config to change.

Comment: @Rick James, yes you are right. I have solved the problem. I will post it as an answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

Following the steps described in this link solved my problem:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-mysql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-16-04